# Writing a more refined and simplified null check c#

Tags: c#, null, nullable, null-check

I have the following code,

```
bool HasPassed= (result!= null && result.Identifier.Equals("Passed"))? true : false
```

This works fine as it is, but I was wondering if it were possible to write this code in a better and more simplified way, maybe using the ? operator ( or  Null-coalescing operator). I'm still learning about this and did not quite understand how it can be used in this case. Below is a minimal project to test it out and any advice is much appreciated!

```
Result result = new Result();
//result.Identifier = "Passed";
result = null;
bool HasPassed = (result != null && result.Identifier.Equals("Passed")) ? true : false;

public class Result
{
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `result?.Identifier == "Passed"`

Comment: Thanks but the issue I don't always know when exactly this property is been set, thus, I need to do the null check when evaluating for bool HasPassed

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-

Comment: If `result` is null, then `result?.Identifier` is null, which is not equal to "Passed".

Comment: Thanks@JohnathanBarclay I got it now!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, any time you have a conditional of the form `condition ? true : false`, you can just replace it with `condition`.

So you can start with:

```cs
bool HasPassed= (result!= null && result.Identifier.Equals("Passed"));
```

You can then remove the parentheses and rename the local variable to follow .NET naming conventions:

```cs
bool hasPassed = result != null && result.Identifier.Equals("Passed");
```

Finally, use the null-conditional operator and the `==` overload for string:

```cs
bool hasPassed = result?.Identifier == "Passed";
```

Just as safe, but much more readable and concise IMO.